# Show text if information has been updated else hide

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pseudocode, if-statement

I'm wondering if someone can help me. I'm sure this will be pretty simple.

I have a form that users can update their account info in. On the profile it prints this info out. But if its empty is their anyway of hiding the text beside it.

FOR EXAMPLE 
I would like to hide 'Works at' if $data['work'] is empty.

```
<?php echo "Works at ".$data['work']."" ?>
```

I was going to try a case and break with status 1 in the database. But with their being so much info I don't think its possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if(!empty($data['work']))
  echo "Works at ".$data['work'];
?>
```

**edit:** to be really sure that the user did not type in some whitespaces, you can extend it bei trimming the value:

```
<?php
$trimmed = trim($data['work']);
if(!empty($data['work']))
  echo "Works at ".$data['work'];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you 32bitfloat, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Done. Could the someone who has downvoted please leave a comment so that if there is an error in my post, everybody knows of it?

Comment: I've upvoted and accepted your answer. I would also like to know if anyone thinks theirs an error as it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($data['work'] != ""): ?>
  Works at <?php echo $data['work']; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or

```
<?php
if ($data['work'] != "") {
  echo "Works at ".$data['work'];
}
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
echo ($data['work'] != "") ? "Works at ".$data['work'] : null;
?>
```

You can use trim-function to be sure that a string with only whitespaces will be matched by this condition too: `trim($data['work'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator, checking that an empty space hasn't been provided by trimming first

```
echo trim($data['work']) != '' ? 'Works at ' . $data['work'] : '';
```

Its also a good practice to escape output using htmlentities

```
echo trim($data['work']) != '' ? 'Works at ' . htmlentities($data['work'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') : '';
```